# Spark Streaming updateStateByKey with tuple as a value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

is it possible to use `updateStateByKey()` function with a tuple as a value? I am using PySpark and my input is `(word, (count, tweet_id))`, which means `word` is a key and a tuple `(count, tweet_id)` is a value. The task of `updateStateByKey` is for each word to sum their counts and create a list of all tweet_ids which contains the word.

I implemented following update function, however I got error list index out of range for `new_values` with index 1:

```
def updateFunc(new_values, last_sum):
  count = 0
  tweets_id = []
  if last_sum:
    count = last_sum[0]
    tweets_id = last_sum[1]
  return sum(new_values[0]) + count, tweets_id.extend(new_values[1])
```

And calling the method:

```
running_counts.updateStateByKey(updateFunc)
```

Comment: can u share the pyspark code so I can try such an example myself. wondering why -1 was given

Comment: I encountered this problem in this project https://github.com/dmacjam/twitter-word-cloud/blob/master/processing/trending_words.py

Comment: thx, will try and got rid if minus 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was with [checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) which means the current state is persisted to the disk in case of a failure. It caused problems because when I changed my definition of a state, in checkpoint it was in the old state without a tuple. Therefore, I deleted checkpoint from the disk and implement the final solution as:

```
def updateFunc(new_values, last_sum):
  count = 0
  counts = [field[0] for field in new_values]
  ids = [field[1] for field in new_values]
  if last_sum:
    count = last_sum[0]
    new_ids = last_sum[1] + ids
  else:
    new_ids = ids
  return sum(counts) + count, new_ids
```

Finally, the answer to my question is: yes, the state can be a tuple or any other data type for storing more values.